# Adding elements to a field widget

Tags: 8, entities

What I need to accomplish is adding a link to a node to field widgets (the node contains the formatted instructions to properly compile the field).
The goal is something like this:

[image]

"What is this?" is the link to a node, to be opened in a new tab or in a popup. In this example the field is a select, but it could be any type of field.

So far I've been able to add the node reference field in the field config form, using Third Party Settings:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'field_config_edit_form' && $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->get('entity_type') == 'myentity') {

    $field = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $help_page_id = $field->getThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'help_page_id');

    $form['help_page_id'] = array(
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#title' => t('Help page'),
      '#target_type' => 'node',
      '#selection_handler' => 'default',
      '#selection_settings' => array(
        'target_bundles' => array('help_page'),
      ),
      '#default_value' => $help_page_id ? Node::load($help_page_id) : NULL,
      '#weight' => 100,
    );

    $form['#entity_builders'][] = 'mymodule_form_field_config_edit_form_builder';
  }
}
```

Now I'm having troubles retrieving this information when showing the form, and altering the field widget in order to display the link.
Using hook_field_widget_form_alter, I cannot get the custom configuration value from the arguments I have:

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {

}
```

I guess I have to load the field configuration entity, but I don't know how.

Comment: You should share the code you have tried. Also, there's always the option of implementing a custom widget that extends from the default. Thanks to OOP, you can simply call the parent and then extend the build render array.

Comment: Hello there, I still don't understand exactly what you want to achieve.
Could you post the code you have tried and rephrase a little bit the description ?
@

Comment: Hello, I've edited the original message. Hope it's clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why do you need entity reference in case you just need a simple link that is pointing towards a specific node ?

Comment: Because I want the admin users to be able to associate a node to a field knowing only the node title. I know I can use html inside the description field, but I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: What I meant is to have this $form['help_page_id'] as type #markup , where you generate the link based on $help_page_id = $field->getThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'help_page_id');

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I've not be very clear. Consider two steps: the first one is field configuration, in which I create a relation between the field and a node. This step was achieved using Third Party Settings and the entity autocomplete field. The second step is outputting the field widget with the extra element (the node link). I'm stuck in this step because I don't know how to get the extra setting.

Comment: What is the final solution for this? How to add additional elements to field settings form?

Comment: To clarify, you're wanting to add an autocomplete entity reference field to the field settings form and have the results displayed in the field's widget settings. Is this correct? Regarding OOP alternatives, there's still no clean equivalent to hook_form_alter() in Drupal 8 that I can determine. Extending the base class with a custom widget doesn't allow multiple modules to alter the same form.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the following:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;
```

I'm assuming your function `mymodule_form_field_config_edit_form_builder()` looks something like this:

```
/**
 * My module form builder to map values to third party settings.
 */
function mymodule_form_field_config_edit_form_builder($entity_type, FieldConfig $field, &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $field->setThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'help_page_id', $form_state->getValue('help_page_id'));
}
```

In your widget form alter you'd access the settings with with FieldConfig. This would add it to all field types, you can check `$field_name` if you want to filter it a bit.

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  $field_name = $context['items']->getName();
  $field = FieldConfig::loadByName('node', 'myentity', $field_name);
  $help_page_id = $field->getThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'help_page_id');
}
```